# How can I set the bottom margin of a div equal to it's height (height will vary)?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin

The issue I'm having may have a different and simpler solution than the one I'm attempting, so I'll explain in full so people can offer other answers.

I'm building a responsive theme on a platform similar to Shopify, in which clients will be taking widget areas and filling them with content of their own.  In the footer I've got 3 divs one of 25% width to the left, one of 50% width in the center, and another of 25% to the right.  I don't use the term float for now, because I'm wanting the center div (50%) to go 100% width and take the highest position when the resolution <= 992px (Bootstraps col-sm breakpoint).

This code demonstrates what I'm trying to do. It may not be possible with pure CSS, so feel free to offer any solution you can think of.

HTML

```
<div class="center-div">
   /* user content of varying height */
</div>
<div class="left-div">
   /* user content */
</div>
<div class="right-div">
   /* user content */
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.center-div {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: /* negative and equal to the height of the user's content */
}

.left-div {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.right-div {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
.center-div { width: 100%; margin: 0px; }
.left-div { width: 50%; }
.right-div { width: 50%; }
}
```

*  EDIT  ***

Never mind folks.  I'm making this entirely too difficult.  About a minute after posting this I realized I could just wrap it all in a relative div and give the left and right divs absolute positioning until the break point.
[**Fiddle for the curious**](http://jsfiddle.net/tim_stuff/U3Lr6/)
However, feel free to answer the question if you want, because I'd like to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Put first Divs Float Left and Right, and then the Content.

If there's space between Left and Right floated divs, Content will fill it. (L:25 / C:50 / R:25)
If not, Content will break. (L: 50/ R: 50 // C:100)

```
<div class="left-div">
    /* user content */
</div>
<div class="right-div">
    /* user content */
</div>
<div class="center-div">
    /* user content of varying height */<br>
    /* user content of varying height */<br>
    /* user content of varying height */<br>
    /* user content of varying height */<br>
    /* user content of varying height */<br>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-div {
    background-color: #a99;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

.right-div {
    background-color: #9a9;
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
}

.center-div {
    background-color: #99a;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .center-div { width: 100%; }
    .left-div, .right-div { width: 50%; }
}
```

To all divs have same height in all occasions:

```
$('.left-div, .right-div').height(function(){
    return $('.center-div').height();
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5VgPz/3)**

Comment: Thanks for the help! Both these are useful in making the height match (something I didn't know how to do), but that wasn't the issue I was trying to resolve.  The problem was with responsive design and wanting the center div to be first in the flow at lower resolutions though appearing 2nd in the flow at higher rez.  I've put together a fiddle with the solution that I came up with here

http://jsfiddle.net/tim_stuff/U3Lr6/

I'll add it to my original post.